# Registering an event handler for a single list

Tags: sharepoint, moss, event-handling

I have a sharepoint event handler which I want to activate for a single list, not all the lists in the site. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer. We need to run this code, maybe in a console app. I still didn't get how to remove the event handler once it has been added though...

```
string siteUrl = Console.ReadLine();
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl);
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
string listName = Console.ReadLine();

SPList list = web.Lists[listName];
string assemblyName = "Issue.EventHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,    PublicKeyToken=89fde668234f6b1d";
string className = "Issue.EventHandler.IssueEventHandler";

list.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdated, assemblyName, className);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just that list or that list in each site ?
I have been testing the code that run when the event happens and I have used a [nice little tool](http://www.wssdemo.com/Lists/Resources/DispForm.aspx?ID=731) from u2u, which allows me to add or remove event handlers per list.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475328.aspx) is a nice primer.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is the "[SharePoint Events Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/speventsmanager)".

> Events Manager is a Feature for SharePoint that allows administrators to manage events attached to their site's lists and document libraries directly using their browser.
>
> This simple feature enables management of events on lists and document libraries through a new item on list settings menu.
>
> You can view, add and delete events, and even find automatically interesting classes and events from an assembly name.
>
> You can download this feature here, and install it using "stsadm -o addsolution -filename GatWeb.SharePoint.EventsManager.wsp".
>
> This feature is localized in french and english.

Answer (score 2):

I recently gave a talk at our Sharepoint SIG about this very problem. The slides and tools are [available here](http://www.mobiusdevelopment.com/dev/Download.asp?ArticleID=1802313708980020849).
You can

- write a console app to do this
- write a features that uses the code in your console app to deploy to the proper list
- use PowerShell
- use Brian Wilson's [admin tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-3-register-event-handlers-plus-free-site-settings-manage-event-handlers-add-on.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for removing event handlers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < olist.EventReceivers.Count; i++) {
    olist.EventReceivers[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code that comes with the tool from u2u that I posted earlier. It is a convenient tool when you are working with event handlers.

Comment: It even allows you to remove eventhandlers :-)